# Нужны ли кавычки, если есть тире?

Tags: пунктуация, тире, кавычки

Подскажите, пожалуйста, нужно ли заключать в кавычки слово "инженер-технолог", если перед ним стоит тире в предложении:

*В 1978 г. окончила факультет технологии деревообработки Курского лесотехнического института по специальности «технология деревообработки», квалификация — «инженер-технолог»*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Верная запись: В 1978 г. окончила факультет технологии деревообработки Курского лесотехнического института по специальности «Технология деревообработки», квалификация — инженер-технолог.

Квалификация - это профессия, в кавычки не берётся, а специализаия пишется в кавычках и чаще с большой буквы. Тире ставят как тире между подлежащим и сказуемым, но в самих документах раньше не ставили.

Comment: А если без тире, то кавычки нужны? Дело в том, что корректор как-то правил мне текст и отметил, что перед "инженер-технолог" желательно тире, так как в другом месте текста у меня была конструкция "звание — сержант, должность — командир отделения", чтобы уравновесить, так сказать.

Comment: @Людмила, а почему квалификация не выделяется? Какая разница, профессия или нет. Это же условное название.

Comment: Как правильно написать "квалификация менеджер"? Менеджер с большой буквы? В кавычках? Или просто квалификация менеджер?  ***Ответ справочной службы русского языка***

    Корректно: _квалификация «менеджер»_

Comment: Грамота.ру, как видно, везде советует брать в кавычки.

Comment: Хотя в дипломе в кавычки не берут.

Comment: Вот и я вижу, что и специальность и квалификация берутся в кавычки. Вопрос в том, нужны ли кавычки, если перед квалификацией тире.

Comment: Думаю, в подобных случаях при наличии тире кавычки не нужны. Поскольку тире здесь присоединяет подлежащее к сказуемому.

Comment: Видимо, следует воспользоваться такими  рекомендациями : https://popravilam.com/blog/048-specialnost-kafedra-kurs.html  Справочники рекомендаций не дают, каждый вуз сам определяет, как писать. У меня в дипломе вообще нет кавычек и всё со строчной буквы, у мужа специальность в кавычках и с большой буквы. Я написала с большой, потому что  последнее время постоянно наблюдаю такую практику оформления работ и резюме в требованиях учебных заведений, но это не последняя инстанция, конечно. Раньше одна практика была, теперь другая, я подумала, что теперь такое требование. Думаю, можно  и  так, и так.

Comment: Серж, разница между названием профессии (квалификации) и специализации всё же есть, это сейчас всё свели к единообразному написанию. Специализация - это название курса, направление,поэтому в кавычках, а профессия  менеджер, как и  профессия водитель -  похоже на правило  сочетания двух нарицательных существительных, когда первое из них обозначает родовое понятие, а второе – видовое: цветок хризантема, газ кислород. Профессия менеджер легко из приложения переходит в несогласованное определение - профессия менеджера, так правильнее, кавычки указывают на рассогласованность: профессия "менеджер".

Comment: Вот здесь ещё есть https://popravilam.com/blog/048-specialnost-kafedra-kurs.html  И ещё:Подскажите, как будет правильней: "Дело в том, что моя девушка по специальности — «режиссер театрализованных представлений», работает в Доме Дружбы." или "Дело в том, что моя девушка по специальности — режиссер театрализованных представлений, работает в Доме Дружбы." То есть, вроде бы специальность пишется в кавычках с маленькой буквы, но тут ведь специальность - сказуемое.
Ответ справочной службы: Использовать кавычки нет необходимости.
http://www.gramota.tv/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D1%81%D0%BF%D0

Comment: @Людмила, у меня в дипломе тоже нет кавычек после слова пррфессия. А вот специальность да, в кавычках, с прописной.

Comment: Если есть согласование, согласен, кавычки не нужны: профессия менеджера.